# how add .net framework 4 in installshield 2010

Tags: installshield

i am going to make setup file with installshield 2010.(my program is written .net frame work 4). according to installation requirement in install shield, i mark microsoft  .net framework 4 full full and client package but after make set up when i want to set the setup file, there is error that "you must have .net framework 4 in your system".
i want to set the .net framework 4.0 during the installation in client computer, but i face with that error:you must have .net framework 4 in your system.
please help me

Answer (score 5):

I realize that this is an old thread, but I came upon it while searching for an answer to the same question.

In my version of InstallShield 2010 Professional, the .Net 4.0 redistributable was not available and, as 2010 is no longer supported, you could not get it from the redistributable downloader in the Tools menu.  There is a [InstallShield 2010 Expansion Pack patch](https://flexeracommunity.force.com/customer/articles/en_US/INFO/Q209084) that can be downloaded and run which will include it.

I installed it and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

Do you use Prerequisites in InstallShield?
If yes, please check if this prerequisite is downloaded to you local system.

You can see this here: 
`"Application Data->Prerequisites->Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 Full"` column `Location`

If it has value "Needs to be downloaded" do the right click and choose `Download selected item...`

Comment: in column location for .net framework 4.0 full is written install locally. but when i want to build i have 2 error.
Error -5054: Could not determine the size of the file "[1]".
Error: -1007: Cannot copy source <PATH>\English (United States).txt to target <PATH>\English (United States).txt"

Comment: I'm not sure the errors you get are related to .net framework prerequisite. What is going on if you disable the prerequisite? Do you still get the errors?

Comment: I have solved my problem but when i to execute the setup file it wants to download .net framework 4 from internet but i want to install .net framework 4 automatically.

Comment: @Mohsen: How did solve the problem with your error Error -5054?